# Is it possible to call a function string in ng-click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs

I'm returning the function as string from json.

The JSON is something like the following.

```
menu:[
  {action:"setItem()", p1:"{{this}}", text:"Add Item"},
  {action:"removeItem()", p1:"{{this}}", text:"Remove Item"}
]

<div ng-repeat="menuList in menu">
  <a href="#" ng-click="menu.action">{{menu.text}}</a>
</div>
```

How can i call function by ng click ie calling setItem() wheng click Add Item.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure you can do what you're asking. If you can the json to this:

```
menu:[
  {action: setItem, p1:"{{this}}", text:"Add Item"},
  {action: removeItem, p1:"{{this}}", text:"Remove Item"}
]
```

And the ng-click to ng-click="menu.action()" it will work

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="{{menu.action}}">{{menu.text}}</a>
```